# "Вмикач" чи "вимикач"? Суто побутове запитання з української мови

Tags: різниця-між-словами, іменники

Працюю в досить перспективній фірмі на посаді провідного спеціаліста по розвитку, при цьому намагаюсь спілкуватися українською мовою правильно. Отож, виникло у мене запитання: як правильно називається пристрій для вмикання і вимикання електричного струму. Зазвичай в народі його називають «включатєль». Шановні відвідувачі та експерти сайту допоможіть! Як правильно казати «вмикач» чи «вимикач», так як в різних джерелах зустрічається різне тлумачення.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на запитання, не заохочують інших до того, щоб надавати відповіді.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити запитання, для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Є подібне запитання англійською: [«Is there any difference between „вимикач“ and „вмикач“ and is it good to use „перемикач“ instead of the two?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1426).

Answer (score 2):

[СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15265&page=502) містить обидва слова:

> **ВМИКА́Ч**, а́, ч. Пристрій для вмикання механізмів, приладів і т. ін. Марушка шаснула до ліжка і клацнула вмикачем. Світло погасло (В.
>   Дрозд); Коли вмикається покажчик повороту, струм від акумуляторної
>   батареї автомобіля (або генератора) через вмикач запалювання надходить
>   на затискач переривника (з наук. літ.); Стартер умикається повертанням
>   ключа вмикача запалювання праворуч до упору (з навч. літ.); На панелі
>   управління кухонною витяжкою – вмикач електровентилятора, перемикач
>   швидкостей, вмикач освітлення (з мови реклами).
>
> **ВИМИКА́Ч**, а́, ч. Пристрій для вмикання і вимикання електричного
>   струму. – Марія Іванівна натиснула вимикач лампи – і зразу весь
>   кабінет зник у півсутіні (В. Собко); Клацнув вимикач, з сусідньої
>   кімнати ввірвалося світло (А. Дімаров); Хотів [Борозна] ввімкнути
>   світло, вже намацав вимикач, а тоді опустив руку (Ю. Мушкетик).

У першого з них більш широке значення, воно може стосуватися будь-якого приладу, що може вмикатися. Друге може стосуватися лише подачі струму. Отже, щом запалити лампу, можете скористатися *вмикачем* або *вимикачем*. Але, наприклад, сигналізація, запалювання автомобіля, радіо приводяться в дію *вмикачем*.

Answer (score 0):

Про це питання йдеться в [Експрес-уроках](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySZQ3JqUxlg):

Правильно і вмикач, і вимикач (пристрій для вмикання і вимикання електричного струму). Але якщо на електроприладі є дві кнопки, то ту, яка вмикає струм ми називаємо "вмикачем", а ту яка вимикає - "вимикачем", але так як таке трапляється рідко, то ми можемо без проблем вживати як "вмикач", так і "вимикач".